# Question regarding Stokes' theorem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

So I'm very rusty on Stokes' theorem, and I have a test about line integrals, surface integrals and such. While practicing, I came across the question, Evaluate the following Line integral:

$$\int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$$
$$ \vec{F}(x,y,z) = (3z - 2y)\hat{i} + (4x - 3y)\hat{j} + (x+2y)\hat{k}, \hspace{.5cm} C: x^2 + y^2 = 1,\hspace{0.5cm} z = 3$$
now I want to use Stokes' theorem to evaluate this line integral.

$$\int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_\limits{S}( \nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot\hat{n}dS$$

So I calculate $\nabla \times \vec{F} = 2\hat{i} - 2\hat{j} + 6\hat{k}$.
When I looked up how to find a unit normal vector to a surface $S$, I found that $\hat{n} = \frac{\nabla G}{||\nabla G||}$, for some $G$ whose level surface is $S$. However, I can't figure out what the equation to the surface is. Can the surface be any smooth surface whose boundary is $C$? In that case can I use $S: z = 3$ as my surface? In which case $G(x,y,z) = 3 - z$. However, doing so results in $\hat{n} = -\hat{k}$, and $dS = dA$. This results in the integral $$\iint\limits_{R} -6dA$$.
This integral is equal to the area of the Region $R$ times $-6$, which is equal to $-6\pi$. However, the answer key claims that the answer is $6\pi$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please don't use $F$ for a vector field and for a function defining a surface. No, you are confusing the level set of a function and the graph of a function. Before you write formulas, why don't you say in *words* what surface $S$ you want whose boundary is $C$?

Comment: I don't know what surface to use myself. Does a semisphere with radius 1 work?.

Comment: Your goal (usually) should be to pick the simplest possible answer. There are zillions of possible surfaces. What's simplest for this curve?

Comment: You changed to $G$, but you're still confusing what you looked up. This applies to a *level surface of $G$*, and the graph (over a suitable domain) of the function $G$ you wrote down is something totally different. So you need to do more review on these matters. In the meantime ... what's the simplest surface whose boundary is $C$?

Comment: Would that be a paraboloid? Also I think I see what you mean now. I would need $G = \sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2} + 3 - z$ correct? That would give me a normal vector to $z = \sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2} + 3$

Comment: Yes, you can create a level set of a graph by that trick. Good. But, come on, you are getting more complicated surfaces, not simpler ones. You have a circle sitting in a plane.

Comment: Oh yeah, I can simply use $z = 3$ and restrict its domain to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Comment: However, by doing so I get $G = 3 - z$, which results in $\hat{n} = -\hat{k}$. $dS = dA$. With that, the integral becomes $$\iint\limits_{R} -6dA$$, the double integral is the area of the circle times $-6$, so the final result should be $-6\pi$. But the answer key says it is $6\pi$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you have to worry about orientation. And don't use that silly formula to find the normal to a plane $z=3$. You *know* what the normal is. But you have to choose the right sign to be compatible with the orientation of $C$, per Stokes. Note that you never stated which direction you go around $C$; that has to be part of what's specified in the problem.

Comment: The problem does not specify what direction you go around C unfortunately, but I'm going to assume that it is counterclockwise, since the answer is positive.